# Why do I get runtime error with Visual C++ when I install Virtualbox (Windows 10)?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, visual-studio, gaming

I hope someone here has a deep understanding of the subject and can help me, because the usual methods unfortunately did not work.

My PC is new and has good hardware (Ryzen 9 3900X and GeForce RTX 2070 Super).

The problem is, as soon as I download VirtualBox (for Kali Linux) on my PC, I have problems with GPU intensive applications, especially the games. I've already done a clean boot once and after that all programs worked perfectly. But as soon as I download Virtual Box, I get some issues. The interesting thing is that Virtual Box always works very well. But the other applications have runtime errors [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yMGD.jpg). It doesn't always appear immediately. Sometimes after 10 minutes, sometimes after 5 or 2 minutes. I also tried reinstalling Microsoft Visual C ++, but unfortunately it doesn't help.

I am thankful for all help.

Comment: Just to clarify: The issues you noticed: is in on Kali Linux itself - after VirtualBox is installed (whether it is running or not)? Or the Guest OS (Windows 10 running as VM inside Virtualbox)?

Comment: The error suggests that Steam is conflicting with something - possibly Virtual Box.

Comment: @Darius: The issue is not in Kali Linux itself or the Windows10 as VM. The issues occurs on my Main OS